# Enumeration windows via IsWindow

Tags: winapi

Filter the numbers from 0 to 0xFFFFFFFF by IsWindow (N)! = 0, sort and see -

[image: http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/iswindow_raw.png]

-- that the numbers 1) N,  2) AND(N,0xFFFF),  3) OR(N,0xFFFF0000) - can serve as a hwnd of the same window.

Hence the question: is it possible to store 2 hwnd in 1 dword, and if not - please provide concrete counterexample. Thanks.

Comment: See [How are window manager handles determined in Windows NT?](http://ppe.blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/17/3903614.aspx).

Comment: Also see [How are window manager handles determined in 16-bit Windows and Windows 95?](http://ppe.blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/16/3885472.aspx), [Why are kernel HANDLEs always a multiple of four?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/21/358109.aspx), [What possible use are those extra bits in kernel handles? Part 1: Sentinels](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/27/8898863.aspx), [What possible use are those extra bits in kernel handles? Part 2: Overcoming limited expressiveness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/28/8902173.aspx)

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @Cody Gray: just wanted to verify the accuracy of its assumptions about the meaning of h-word in hwnd. Now thanks GSerg (link to an article about undocumented details of NT Windows first hand) -  I know that I was right :)

Answer (score 3):

It *is* possible to store an HWND in just 16 bits. In fact, you could even store it in 15 bits, as it is always even.

But what you should ask instead is: is it wise to do that? The answer is **no**! The documentation for the Win32 API states that an HWND is a 32-bit integer, but says nothing about it internal structure. These are undocumented implementation details that are subject to change in any version of the system.

Any technique that takes advantage of this knowledge will be frowned upon by any responsible programmer. That doesn't mean that it can't be useful, just that you have to be careful with what you know.