# HWND from Spy++ Window Handle

Tags: winapi

Spy++ gives you the hex value of a window handle. I am want to take in this number value and create the `HWND` from that value but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

This is what I have tried:

```
_tprintf(_T("What is the window handle?\r\n")); 

HWND hWnd;
_tscanf(_T("%x"), &hWnd);   

if(!IsWindow(hWnd))
{
    _tprintf(_T("This is not a window\r\n"));
}
else
{
    _tprintf(_T("This is a window\r\n"));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I misunderstand something?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but do you really need to support ASCII builds? i.e. Why use TCHAR / _tprintf? Just use the wide versions. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx - "New applications should always call the Unicode versions. Many world languages require Unicode. If you use ANSI strings, it will be impossible to localize your application. The ANSI versions are also less efficient, because the operating system must convert the ANSI strings to Unicode at run time."

Comment: I don't actually. I read somewhere that it was a good idea to use TCHAR but I don't have a need for it nor a very good reason to use it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Spy++ isn't how you should be retrieving a window handle. It's what you should be using to get the information you need in order to be able to *find the window handle yourself* at the time you need to find it (a window classname, unique caption, or combination of the above) using `FindWindow` or `FindWindowEx`, which will return you a real, current `HWND` with no conversion of any kind needed. If you take another approach and ask a different question ("How do I use the information from Spy++?", for instance), you might have better luck.

Comment: @Ken Thanks, I was basically trying to see if I was going the long way around by using `FindWindow` or a variant thereof.

Comment: An `HWND` is a pointer. Try using `%p` instead of `%x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A thread should not use `IsWindow` for a window that it did not create
>   because the window could be destroyed after this function was called.
>   Further, because window handles are recycled the handle could even
>   point to a different window.

Comment: So I basically need to use `FindWindow` I can't take a shortcut?

Comment: @Mark Ingram: since the window could be destroyed after FindWindow was called, - does this mean that a thread should not use FindWindow ? :-)

Comment: @kero I don't know, it's a good question, and the docs don't mention the same problem in `FindWindow`.

Comment: As @kero points out, you have a [TOCTTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race condition, either way. This is not an answer to the question. What the quote is trying to say is the following: Make sure your window does not get destroyed in between calling `IsWindow` and another operation. The only way to ensure this is to call both `IsWindow` and this other operation on the same thread that created the window, without yielding control to the system in between the calls.

Comment: @IInspectable: btw, I was quite surprised by the negative (-1) reaction of some members on the interesting results of my experiment with IsWindow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727815/enumeration-windows-via-iswindow